# Referencing cells in tables on a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to automatically format a table in a Google Doc cell by cell. Once I have a table stored in the variable `table`, I try to use `getCell` to reference the cell in the top left of this table, but it doesn't return the cell I'm after.

I noticed that in the Google Scripts reference, they note that to point to a cell, the correct usage is `getCell(rowIndex, cellIndex)`. What does `cellIndex` refer to in this case, and does it relate to some sort of `columnIndex`?

Any pointers on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Editing a table in a Google Doc

Here's an example that edits all of the cell contents of a table selected by placing the cursor inside one of it's cells.

rowIndex goes from 0 to `table.getNumRows()-1;`

cellIndex goes from 0 to `table.getRow(i).getNumCells()-1`

```
function editTableAtCursor(){
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var el=doc.getCursor().getElement().getParent().getParent().getParent();
  var table=el.asTable();
  var rows=table.getNumRows();
  for(var i=0;i<table.getNumRows();i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<table.getRow(i).getNumCells();j++) {
      table.getCell(i,j).editAsText().setText(Utilities.formatString('Row: %s Cell: %s',i,j));
    }
  }
}
```

- [Table Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table)
- [Example that replaces table with an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585391/7215091)

Comment: Thanks for this! I guess I didn't realise that you need to specify the row number before being able to get the table help. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the cellIndex refers to columnIndex. Consider the below example

```
    function getCellVal() {

  var docBody=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var table=docBody.getTables()[0];
  Logger.log(table.getCell(0,0).getText())

}
```

Here, the value in Logger will retrieve the cell value in first row and first column of the table. the index for row and column starts from 0.

Hope this helps!.